# Audio issues with asterisk 13

Tags: asterisk, nat

I have two extensions registered to asterisk (asterisk has a real IP), both of them behind NAT, and every one of them belong to a different LAN network.

The SIP work just fine (i.e: the extensions can call each other), but there is no voice at all.

I configure natting and media in sip.conf in asterisk as follow:

```
nat=force_rtp,comedia
directrtpsetup=yes
```

Note: when i put the extensions in the same NAT, there is no problem, both SIP and RTP work just fine.

does anybody knows what is the problem or how to solve it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, idescovered the problem and its solution.
first of all, the wright NAT options are:

```
nat=force_rport,comedia
```

second,  the wright media option is:

```
directmedia=no
```

my problem was related to opened port, in rtp.conf i put:

```
rtpstart=1111
rtpend=2222
```

but in the server the range of the opened port is {44444 --> 55555}
and because of that there wasn't voice between the callee and the caller.

Answer (score 0):

> Asterisk 1.8: The 'nat' option has now been been changed to have yes,
>   no, force_rport, and comedia as valid values. Setting it to yes forces
>   RFC 3581 behavior and enables symmetric RTP support. Setting it to no
>   only enables RFC 3581 behavior if the remote side requests it and
>   disables symmetric RTP support. Setting it to force_rport forces RFC
>   3581 behavior and disables symmetric RTP support. Setting it to
>   comedia enables RFC 3581 behavior if the remote side requests it and
>   enables symmetric RTP support.

force_rtp is not valid option. Force_rport,comedia are mutially exclusive options.
Directrtpsetup most likly will not work if both clients NATed.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
actually the option is:
nat=force_rport,comedia
as you mentioned 

if (directrtpsetup=yes) option doesn't work, what option should i use to solve the audio issue?

Comment: How i can know what type of nat you have? directrtp very rarely work if you have nat on both end. Options you refer NOT WORK when used both at same time.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply :)
i figured out the solution.